# How to get Facebook feeds by using different user credential instead of developer account credential for a Windows Phone 8 application?

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 application, I had integrated Facebook for authentication and feeds purpose. The problem I am facing is that if I logged in with developer account, everything works fine(means I am getting user information and feeds). But if I logged in with some other credential I am unable to get user feeds and application gets crash.

Answer (score 0):

The necessary permissions for this is read_stream, and you most likely did not get it approved: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

I am afraid you will not get it approved at all for a Windows Phone application:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2